# Within X days from due date / till the due date

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

we are issuing invoice as a company and in our templates we have:

**In the event that the issued invoice is not paid within 7 days from the due date defined on the invoice, Supplier shall have the right...**

OR

**In the event that the issued invoice is not paid till due date defined on the invoice, Supplier shall have the right...**

---

My understanding is that if it is period of more days, we should use "within" however if it is one exact day, we should use till due date and using this:

**In the event that the issued invoice is not paid within due date**

would be wrong.

Am I right?

Comment: If you have a due date of "31 October", when must the invoice be paid? 31 October or 7 November?

Comment: 7 November in the first case, 31 October in the 2nd one.

Comment: Related: [Interpret the phrase “within a month of the first Sunday in June”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447899).

Answer (score 1):

"The due date" suggests the last possible date that payment can be made (i.e. *is due*).

I would say either:
**in the event that the issued invoice is not payed *by* the due date defined on the invoice...** (pay any time from now until the date specified)

or:

**in the event that the issued invoice is not paid *within* 7 days from *the date* defined on the invoice...** (pay any time in the week following the date specified).

If you use till/until, this suggests you don't want payment before the date specified: "please do not pay until the date specified on the invoice". This does not make clear whether you will accept payment *after* the specified date, however.

Comment: There is a difference between 'of' and 'from'. "Within 7 days _of_ the date" means 7 days on either side (before and after). "7 days _from_ the date" specifically means _after._

Comment: Is 'that' required after 'In the event'? It can just be 'In the event the invoice is not paid by or before seven days / by or before due date mentioned on it,....